# Как компилятор/линкер обходится без объектных файлов для template-классов?

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, компиляция, линковка

Собственно в этом вопрос, до неприличия простой, но в гугле не нашел ответа. Компилируя в qtcreator'e заметил, что для шаблонных классов нет соответствующих .o файлов. Ладно, понятно, что нет соответствующего .cpp, но ведь по идее шаблонный класс при использовании динамически генерирует "нормальный" класс с соответствующими типовыми параметрами, так? И как функции этого класса "попадают" в исполняемый файл без посредничества объектных? Напрямую? Если объектные файлы так ненеобходимы, то для чего они вообще до сих пор?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. объектные файлы генерируются не для классов, а для единиц трансляции;
2. тело инстанцированных шаблонов помещается в единицу трансляции, которая их инстанцирует;
3. никто не заставляет явно создавать и использовать объектные файлы, большинство компиляторов позволяют сразу собрать исполняемый файл

Comment: то есть, если проект состоит из десятка темплейтных классов и одного `main.cpp`, где создается объекты этих классов с разными типами, то бинарный код всех этих классов будет в `main.o`?

Comment: @asianirish Да.

Comment: @asianirish, более того, все *одинаковые* "инстанциации" из разных единиц трансляции будут присутствовать в загрузочном модуле ... (такая вот засада)

Comment: @avp В каком загрузочном модуле?

Comment: @VTT, в том, что линкер делает из объектных, в каком же еще.

Comment: @avp Может вы исполняемый файл имеете ввиду?

Comment: @VTT, и так его тоже можно назвать